# The original image from stackoverflow

Tags: discussion

5-6 weeks.... does anyone remember that time? You went to stackoverflow.com and saw a funny picture...

Where can I find that picture?

Comment: [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/172936) perhaps...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean [that one](http://web.archive.org/web/20080912181315/https://stackoverflow.com/)?

[image: The a miracle occurs]

There are many more like this on [sciencecartoonsplus](http://www.sciencecartoonsplus.com). Enjoy.

Comment: That's the one, miracle3. Thanks.

Comment: It's also in the Best Comic Question on SO. I used this in the last week for a presentation at work.

Comment: I am entirely confused by this question and answer. How'd you know this was the image the OP was looking for?

Comment: Reminds me of the Underpants Gnomes' business plan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underpants_Gnomes

Comment: was this on SO front page, as an image ?

Comment: Before SO launched, this picture was shown as a teaser. This was during the 5-6 weeks it always took Jeff to finish (now upgraded to estimating 2.0 it is 6-8 weeks).

Comment: Some of us already had SO as a homepage when Jeff first announced the site URL. However can anyone remember who hacked the beta site first? Or was that information never revealed?

Comment: WHAT WHAT HAHAT? hacked? sweet mother of rumours pelase speak now or take the 2nd door from the left!

Comment: Was it Sasha? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/who-is-sasha-and-why-is-he-a-big-villain

Comment: To answer the question regarding the "hacked" beta from podcast 10: *first of all we did have a beta site up and very clever hacker listeners figured out the URL for our site - not that it's very difficult to figure out [laughing]* - Jeff