# Who is sasha and why is he a big villain?

Tags: discussion, users, moderation

Saw this on reddit,

> [Vim Tricks your mom never told you about -- VERY DARK CORNERS... published by Sasha: the biggest villian on StackOverflow, and now engraved in its WALL of FAME](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9hwus/vim_tricks_your_mom_never_told_you_about_very/)!

and was curious as to what this is all about.

Who is this sasha person and what makes them a big villain?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sasha had some positive traits (believe it or not), but could not be rehabilitated. Final email:

> Based on what I can only call a pattern of repeated and intentional "trolling", the moderator consensus was to place your "Sasha" account on a 4 month timed suspension.
>
> We tried to work with you on this after the first 30-day suspension (and the 'porn' PuzzleCracker incident), but the negative behaviors returned. Your actions on the site continued to cause problems on the site for us.
>
> We feel we have given you ample opportunity to show us that you are working with the community and not against it, and you have not shown a good faith effort.
>
> That said, you are welcome to come back in 4 months if the behavior can be changed.

His response:

> I obviously don't belong on SO, nor my behavior is likely to change. Therefore, Jeff, I request for my account to be deleted from stackoverflow. I apologize for inconveniences I have caused on the site.

My response:

> You are welcome back after 4 months, as long as the behavior improves.
>
> If at that time you still feel the same way, I will delete the account for you, no problem.

Ultimately his account was deleted, per his request.

Perhaps Sasha is a good example of how moderators try in good faith to work with our users, even ones that are problematic. But that's a two-way street, and Sasha was unwilling or unable to meet us halfway.

Comment: What's the ""porn" Puzzlecracker"? :S

Comment: @WilliamHilsum, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782729/need-a-pattern-to-call-verify-method-for-every-instance-method-pattern) that Sasha posted using an alias.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/782729/revisions.

Answer (score 16):

He was more of a really poor court jester than a villain.

In a nutshell, he posted tons of questions of low quality. When people closed his questions down he would go on crusades to get them reopened and basically get into big flame wars with the other users. He had been placed in the penalty box multiple times and if I am not mistaken was caught with a couple duplicate accounts before.

Eventually he went and spammed up meta asking for Atwood to delete his accounts, which we all celebrated with much fanfare.

Comment: I missed all this.  I guess I should consider myself lucky.

Comment: So, would Sasha be considered a "meme" now?

Comment: I must have missed it as well. I've been on SO since the private beta, and I've never heard of this guy.

Answer (score 12):

That link was submitted to reddit by a user named "puzzlecracker" one of Sasha's aliases on Stack Overflow.  Sasha must be very bored and lonely now, since he's taken to vilifying himself on other web sites.  This is a new low, even for Sasha... whatever new user name he's using now (it really is an enigma).

Comment: Well it follows pretty closely with his character. Near the end of his time he was posting his life story on Meta as if he was the world's most notorious crime boss and he had finally been caught.

Comment: God, I'd blocked all this out of my brain. Where's that flashing light thing again?

Comment: He could totally be in the League of Villains!

Comment: Personally, I think he was far more Evil League of Evil material. Bad Horse has been looking for someone to get him some tea, or something.

Comment: @Lucas: He could be our Riddler! :)