# Is it possible to recover an account deleted by SE staff?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, account-recovery

Is it possible to recover an account that was explicitly deleted by a Stack Exchange staff member (as opposed to an elected diamond moderator)? That is, the kind of account where the user requested the deletion, or committed atrocities against the community?

Comment: For instance, Sasha's account?

Comment: I hope Sasha's account was deleted, the disk written over 500 times to remove any magnetic traces, the drive platters melted down into formless lumps, and the lumps placed onto a rocket and shot into the sun.

Comment: I'd be interested to know which account. There was probably a reason it was deleted.

Comment: Looks like sasha's questions are still on SO. His return is unlikely, as he has  already been awarded the highest honor  by entering the SO's Hall of Fame -- per this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/who-is-sasha-and-why-is-he-a-big-villain

My question is general though!

Comment: Yeah. His return is unlikely with that account name... but not *that* unlikely with new account names :)

Comment: Related: *[Who is Sasha and why is he a big villain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/)*

Answer (score 9):

No, this is not possible. Once a profile is deleted, it is gone forever.

We *can* restore past content to a new profile, **but we only do so for users who were deleted erroneously**, usually due to a moderator making a mistake (I've done it a couple of times myself). If you *requested* the deletion in any way, then the content will remain anonymous forever.

By restore content, I mean that posts (questions and answers) and comments which were connected to the previous profile would be attached to a new profile that must be created. This new profile will have a fresh creation date, and won't have any past profile info, votes, favorites, bounties, reviews, or badges (some post-related badges may be automatically re-awarded if you still qualify for them).

Answer (score 8):

It is now, apparently, not current Stack Overflow policy to undelete accounts unless they were deleted in error.

Here's a reply from team@stackoverflow I got when I asked them to undelete my own deleted account on 2016-05-18.

> Unfortunately we do not restore profiles which have been deleted. That
> information on Meta is from 2009 and outdated. Undeleting profiles is
> something we reserve only for users which were deleted in error.