# How to revive my deleted account?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I have been using Stack Overflow for 9 months. After some time, I deleted my account. Now I created my account with same OpenID provider. Apparently, my rewards, reputation, badges are lost. Is there a way to get it all back?

Comment: ok..I wl do that

Comment: (It seems the duplicate also answers your question, Gani.)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. You might want to try to email team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to revive your account.

Comment: Oops, [this might not be true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22568/recover-a-deleted-account/22577#22577): *"Yes, it's possible to recover a deleted account, but it requires "Jeff-level" access. Contact team@stackoverflow.com to get an account undeleted."* Still, the team might have better things to do than delete-undelete-delete and so on... Or [tweet about it](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/2886432981)!

Comment: @Arjan: That's why I said " as far as we, normal users, know". It's not officially that's why I said it.