# For what reasons has my account been removed altogether and not even blocked?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, account-recovery

I have been using SO for about 11 months. Once I lost my first account so then I built up the new one and started gaining reputation again.

I have been busy with my office work so I couldn't find enough time to spend on SO. On Wednesday (26-12-2012) I spent my whole day on SO to answer different questions and to accept the answers to questions that I have asked. I also up voted the answers that helped me and gave me direction. I also up voted the question from which I found some learning material.

**BUT**

The next day I found an email in my inbox that my account has not been blocked but **removed**. And the reasons described in email were that I am supposed to be a **SockPuppet**.

***I object to that; I didn't do anything inappropriate to gain reputation.***

- Is posting an answer to any question wrong or against the policy?
- Is voting the question up wrong or against the policy?
- Is voting the answer up wrong or against the policy?

**OR**

- Is spending 24 hours on Stack Overflow prohibited according to the policy?

If all the things are true then I think the policy should be changed or all the users should be blocked because I see every day others accept answers, vote up answers and do every thing to gain reputation.

If I gained enough reputation in one day then this should be thought that from where I have earned this reputation. Definitely I have earned reputation from the system you have made. I didn't use any wrong means or ways to earn it. **But** I don't know why the system has removed my account without giving me the warning that I am doing something wrong according to the policy.

This is not fair at all. I request to recover my account. I hope the management will listen to my question and make the right decision.

Comment: Gee, I wonder if the timing of this has anything to do with any other recent posts, here...

Comment: Did you have multiple accounts with the same IP?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri That should not matter. My lab mates have the same IP as me. That isn't against the rules.

Comment: similar thing has happened to me on SO. In last few days i built reputation up to some mark but on that very day after few hours i got decrement in my reputation of  34 points neither i get any warning nor any one did vote me down but still i got my reputation went down that is not fair

Comment: @UsmanKurd What happened to you is not at all similar to what this user has done. He was caught cheating.

Comment: @AustinHenley Ok but say that you upvote too much one of your lab, genuinely.They may be thinking that you created your account just to support one friend, or that you're the same person.

Comment: @UsmanKurd If your reputation was decremented, but your account wasn't blocked or removed, and you weren't downvoted etc., it might be because a question that you had given an answer to was deleted. That has happened to me too. It isn't your fault, or because of anything you did necessarily! It was likely several different things happening for it to be 34 points, maybe an answer with 3 up votes (the -30 portion) was deleted plus something else that subtracted 4 rep points.

Comment: @AndrewBarber :: Can you please tell me how you justify that I have cheated? If I start voting up your questions and answers the what SO will do? Will it declare you account fare or ask you that You have a fake account?

Comment: @FeralOink I don't think one can delete a question which is already answered. But OP can take back one accept, and re award to different answer. That might cause a -15 reputation loss..

Comment: I have posted this question to recover my account back, I have many important questions there and I have earned the reputation after striving hard. Is there any official of SO?

Comment: If you are sharing a single internet facing IP address with several other active Stack OVerflow users *and* you have not been voting for one another then you should replay to the email that you recieved explaining the situation. You certainly won't get anywhere by just posting to meta: you have an unusual case and there are no provisions to handle it through the usual channels.

Comment: You say you were told you were using a "Sock Puppet". That is cheating. For an account to actually get *wiped out* is pretty rare, and the mods tend to exercise that option pretty carefully.

Comment: I told that they called me "Sock Puppet". I know what does Sock puppet mean. But I was not a Sock Puppet.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I was going to send this URL to you via Twitter, as I don't want to interfere with the main intent of the original question (I shouldn't have said anything, that's my fault). I saw you don't use Twitter much though. Points removal for deleted questions is not straightforward, per this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/ I only mentioned it, as I lost 35 rep pts from WebApps SE today, for a deleted answer that was accepted from Sept. 2011, so it has been on my mind.

Comment: @dmckee :: I thought that I'll find some officials of SO on Meta. Thats why I posted my query here and tagged the `support` here. 

Can you please tell me the proper channel? 
Can I replay back to that email that came from `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: This comment http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22568/is-it-possible-to-recover-an-account-deleted-at-the-se-team-level?rq=1#comment214579_22577 to an answer in another question says that you should email `team@stackoverflow.com` about recovering a deleted account, or to plea your case, in the current, post-Jeff Atwood era.

Comment: Thanks @FeralOink :: my case is in front of you. What you think? I have right to ask the SO team about my account? If some anonymous member starts voting my questions and answers up that how some one will justify that its fake account even if the account has the same IP (Which was surely not).

Comment: FeralOink is not a moderator or staff member here (neither am I). We don't at all have access to the information that moderators used to determine you should be deleted. So asking our opinion on "your case" is not terribly productive.

Comment: That was a joke. I am sorry. I should delete it. I don't know what StackExchange policy is, nor am I implying that they would do anything of the sort that I described. I am not a moderator. @AndrewBarber is correct. I'm sorry, and will now extract myself, from this, as a StackExchange person is the proper person for you to contact, not me.

Comment: Oh God, I am just asking friendly. I know none of here is moderator. I  don't have enough knowledge of what SO has internal policy of deleting some user.Thats why I asked. I think this isn't enough serious to get friendly opinion about some query that is going to be in front of SO team.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your account was deleted because you admitted to having created several new accounts to circumvent a ban. Saying that publicly, where mods can see, probably influenced one such mod to delete your account.

Comment: I assume that what happened is that you upvoted posts from the same user. This probably raised some flag, and the system (or mods, not sure) thought you are sockpuppet account of that user.

Comment: @simchona :: If you read clearly, then it is written that " I lost my old account" that why I created the new one. And creating a new account on SO means creating a new email ID. I am talking about my current account.

Comment: If you were marked as a sock puppet, check the original account you had. You may have been merged.

Comment: Could you please give an example of one of your old questions?

Comment: example of my old question? What does it mean? Does it mean that I post the link of one of my old question that I asked?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: It blows my mind that you continue this discussion in a public post with people who have no bearing on the outcome.

Answer (score 29):

If your account has been removed, things are past the point that even a diamond moderator can assist you. This is what I recommend you do:

1. Use [this form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) to contact our community management team
2. Indicate that you don't think the destruction of your account was appropriate and give them the following details:

   - Your old user name / ID, a link to where your profile page used to be would be ideal, or a link to one of your questions or answers that now show the 'anonymous' user. This is needed to identify the now defunct account.
   - Why you think the action was unwarranted
   - A copy of the e-mail you received from the moderator that took the action (which *should* also contain the details needed to identify your account)
   - A link to this meta question
3. Wait for a reply, most of the team is on a holiday break, as far as I know.

I have brought this post to the attention of the community team in chat, however as I said, please be patient.

Sorry that I'm unable to do more, as you're obviously quite upset, but the steps above are your clearest path to a favorable resolution.

***Important Note***

Please do not use comments under this answer to request support. Rather, *follow the steps I outlined above* if you want to resolve your concerns. Comments left under this answer requesting support will simply be removed - please follow the instructions given and wait for a response, you'll get one - I promise.

Comment: :: Thank you buddy, Thank you so much. You at least released my some of tension. I definitely provide all the details. I have every thing. 

I have emailed my query to `team@stackoverflow.com`. but I have not get any replay yet.
but now as you told that most of team is on holidays, so I am waiting am let you know if I get a replay from them