# How can an OP lose -1 reputation on an unanswered question

Tags: bug, reputation, down-votes

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160612/for-what-reasons-my-account-has-been-removed-not-even-blocked) is the thread, and it has/had 0 answers at the time of asking this question. But when I went through OP's reputation change I found this

[image]

The line I am concerned about is this

```
 -1        6 mins ago  downvote
```

. 
I am more familiar with Stack Overflow, than Meta. Is Meta's reputation system different? For stackoverflow you can lose -1 reputation **only if you down vote an answer**. **But how can OP lose -1 reputation on an unanswered question?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because of the order of events. The OP only lost 1 reputation from that down vote, because at the time it was cast, *he only had two reputation total*.

He started with 1 rep. Got a +5, two -2's, and then the -1. The other upvotes followed. I'm not certain whether a rep recalc will correct this automatically, but I'm also not sure it really matters.

Comment: Oh.. Ok then one can't have negative or 0 rep..Good.. hadn't thought of that..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Correct; the system has a floor of 1. The hole can only be dug so deep.

Comment: No idea why this question got down voted though

Answer (score 2):

This is because when that user got that downvote he/she had only 2 reputation at that time. And [reputation has lower bound of 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2625/187824)

Answer (score 2):

It appears the user hit the bottom limit for reputation which is 1. You can't have negative rep so the order of events does matter.