# User removed? Why? And most importantly: from what site?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I would like to know why I got this message:

> Mar27 -10 20:31 removed User was removed

I don't remember where I last posted, so, *where* was my user removed from?

Why didn't I get any warning? I don't think I've broken any rules (yes, I've read posts like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161241/user-was-removed-rules)).

I can't imagine why the user would be removed! I mean, to cease its existence!

And without any warning or advice, a MESSAGE... nothing!

Comment: It's not that your user was removed, but a user that had upvoted one of your posts was removed (and his/her vote lost).

Comment: Don't worry, you haven't ceased to exist ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but why I´ve lost TEN POINTS? People in the other post has lost far less! And why am I penalized anyway...

Comment: Yeah, that was my worry! I thought I have literally ceased to exist somewhere, and didn´t know why... :)

Comment: The user that upvoted you has been removed and so have his votes. Thus, 10 reputation is subtracted from that upvote.

Comment: I have seen this misunderstanding several times which suggests the text may need revising to be more clear

Comment: @RichardTingle Related: [Why is the “user was removed” message so vague?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181541/why-is-the-user-was-removed-message-so-vague)