# How to restore the reputation in my deleted account?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I accidentally deleted my Stack Overflow account. Then I created another account using the same email address as my deleted account, hoping that Stack Overflow would recognize my email address and restore the deleted account.

Yes, it worked, my past achievements appeared boxed in green but my 8 reputation was not restored. Instead it went back to 1 reputation (encircled in red).

Is this a bug? What to do now?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what's going on but according to your profile - http://stackoverflow.com/users/5366660/ - you only have the one badge (Informed).

Comment: Yes, after i created the new account i read the tour page and i earned one badge(informed).

Comment: Voting to leave open; I believe this could happen on any SE site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems a bug to me in the code that should trash your notifications when an account is deleted. Apparently they aren't which result in the notifications shown.

As ChrisF already commented, you only have one new badge on your account. All others are gone. The notifications are wrong.

According to [Is it possible to recover an account deleted at the SE team level?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22568/245360), you can recover your account, but that would require someone with database access. As the post says:

> Contact team@stackoverflow.com to get an account undeleted.

I would recommend to do that.

Comment: I already emailed on team@stackoverflow.com. If this is a bug hopefully they can fixed this as soon as possible.And also if they will restore my deleted account hopping my reputations will also be restored. And the notifications will serve as a proof.

Comment: I hope so too for you. *Maybe* the notifications shown can be considered a bug, but I will leave that to you whether you'd report it or not.

Answer (score 5):

At last my problem is solved. After a couple of hours the Stack Overflow Team replied my email. Thanks to Sir Patrick Hofman for his recommendation. And to the Stack Overflow Team. If someone has a similar question can refer to this post.[image]

Comment: You are a lucky man today :)